# Get Module data of a user from Vtiger CRM

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

I am new in vTiger and need to fetch all data from "Project" module for a specific user
Like:
SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE assigned_user_id='9'
I did not find the "assigned_user_id" field in vtiger_project table, so how can we get from it.
My Project fields are as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c2fK.jpg

Please check, and suggest me how to get all project data of a particular user assigned to him.

Comment: please consider selecting my answer as the correct answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM vtiger_project INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON projectid = crmid AND deleted = 0 where smownerid = 1;
```

the **Assigned to** field does not exist in the `vtiger_project` table, instead it is stored int he `vtiger_crmentity` table (that is true for all vtiger modules that have records).

The `delted = 0` condition makes sure the record has not been (logically) deleted on vtiger.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I've misunderstood the question. My answer below is valid when you are using the REST API.

---

According to the result from [ListTypes](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservice_reference_manual#List_Types) the name of the module is `Project`, without the 's'.

[ID's in Vtiger](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservice_reference_manual#Id_Format) are prefixed with the module/object ID and an `x`, so your `9` would actually be:

```
19x9
```

Assuming 19 is the object ID for the user module. It is 19 in my Vtiger V7. You can make sure by calling [Describe](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservice_reference_manual#Describe)

If you need to find the name of the assigned user field, call Describe for the Project module. AFAIK `assigned_user_id` is correct.

Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Project WHERE assigned_user_id='19x9'
```